# How to Run Docker Container Using IBM LSF

Tags: docker, containers, websphere, lsf, rhel8

I am trying to trigger Docker Container using IBM LSF Spectrum bsub commands. OS I am using is RHEL 8.1
I have started IBM LSF , checked it is running using lsid command which shows "cluster name & master name".
under configdir/lsb.params I have  setup dockerapp as well
`#Begin Application`
#NAME = dockerapp
#CONTAINER = docker[image(registry.redhat.io/ubi8/python-36)]
#DESCRIPTION = Docker User Service
#End Application
`
Tried using with "udocker" option as well.

When I run following commands to start docker container. It shows Job  is submitted to default queue . But when I check using `docker ps` , I cannot see any container running.
 `bsub -a docker -app dockerapp sleep 1h`
`bsub -a "docker(registry.redhat.io/ubi8/python-36)" -app udocker a.out -in in.dat -out out.dat`

I have made all the required configurations using LSF 10.1 with installed Fix Pack and getting no errors while `badmin reconfig`

When I do `bjobs <bobid>` for docker jobs its show `STATUS as EXIT`

Any way out I can see Containers running?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out to configure lsb.applications to use Container in "-d" mode in option parameter.